# Retrieving the results from the std::tr1::regex_search

Tags: regex, tr1

I have a confusion on how to fetch the result after running the function regex_search in the std::tr1::regex.
Following is a sample code to demonstrate my issue.

```
string source = "abcd 16000 ";
string exp = "abcd ([^\\s]+)";
std::tr1::cmatch res;
std::tr1::regex rx(exp);

while(std::tr1::regex_search(source.c_str(), res, rx,   std::tr1::regex_constants::match_continuous))
{

   //HOW TO FETCH THE RESULT???????????
   std::cout <<" "<< res.str()<<endl;

   source = res.suffix().str();
}
```

The regular expression mentioned should ideally strip off the "abcd" from the string and return me 16000.

I see that the cmatch res has TWO objects. The second object contains the expected result.(this object has three members (matched, first, second). and the values are {true, "16000", " "}.

My question is what does this size of the object denote? Why is it showing 2 in this specific case( res[0] and res[1]) when I have run regex_search only once? And how do I know which object would have the expected result?

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15339/A-TR1-Tutorial-Regular-Expressions.htm):

> match[0]: represents the entire match
>   match[1]: represents the first match
>   match[2]: represents the second match, and so forth

This means `match[0]` should - in this case! - hold your full `source` (`abcd 16000`) as you match the whole thing, while `match[1]` contains the content of your [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
If there was, for example, a second capturing group in your regex you'd get a third object in the match-collection and so on.

I'm a guy who understands visualized problems/solutions better, so let's do this:
See the [demo@regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rG1oS1).

[image]

See the two colors in the textfield containing the teststring?
The *green color* is the background for your capturing group while the
*blue color* represents everything else generally matched by the expression, but not captured by any group.
In other words: blue+green is the equivalent for `match[0]` and green for `match[1]` in your case.

This way you can always know which of the objects in `match` refers to which capturing group:
You initialize a counter in your head, starting at 0. Now go through the regex from the left to the right, add 1 for each `(` and subtract 1 for each `)` until you reach the opening bracket of the capturing group you want to extract. The number in your head is the array index.

**EDIT**
Regarding your comment on checking `res[0].first`:

The member `first` of the `sub_match` class is only

> denoting the position of the start of the match.

While `second` denotes the position of the end of the match.
(taken from [boost doc](http://boost.cppll.jp/HEAD/libs/regex/doc/sub_match.html))
Both return a `char*` (VC++10) or an `iterator` (Boost), thus you get a substring of the sourcestring as the output (which may be the full source in case the match starts at index zero!).

Consider the following program (VC++10):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string source = "abcdababcdefg";
    string exp = "ab";
    tr1::cmatch res;
    tr1::regex rx(exp);

    tr1::regex_search(source.c_str(), res, rx);

    for (size_t n = 0; n < res.size(); ++n) 
    { 
        std::cout << "submatch[" << n << "]: matched == " << std::boolalpha 
            << res[n].matched << 
            " at position " << res.position(n) << std::endl; 
        std::cout << "  " << res.length(n) 
            << " chars, value == " << res[n] << std::endl; 
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 

    cout << "res[0].first: " << res[0].first << " - res[0].second: " << res[0].second << std::endl;
    cout << "res[0]: " << res[0];

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Execute it and look at the output. The first (and only) match is - obviously - the first to chars `ab`, so this is actually the whole matched string and the reason why `res[0] == "ab"`.
Now, knowing that `.first`/`.second` give us substrings from the start of the match and from the end of the match onwards, the output shouldn't be confusing anymore.

Comment: Consider this. The source = "abcdabcdabcd" and the exp = "ab". The tool highlights ab in blue colour.  However when I execute this code using regex, the result size is 1. and it res[0].first is "abcdabcdabcd". I believe that the reg exp "ab" on "abcdabcdabcd" should return "ab".  What is wrong here?

Comment: Wrong here is that you call `res[0].first`. Check the content of `res[0]`: it is `ab`!